По всем законам справедливости - нужно ли обособление?
Нужны ли запятые (или запятая) в следующем предложении:
И (,) по всем законам справедливости (,) ты самая настоящая пособница преступления.

Основной вариант:
И по всем законам справедливости / ты самая настоящая пособница преступления.
Пояснение

Обособление  обстоятельственного оборота со значением соответствия в общем случае факультативно и зависит от различных факторов.  Здесь нераспространенный оборот входит в  состав простого предложения,  нет особых причин для его обособления.

В то же время при актуализации (подчеркивании) оборота обособление возможно (выбор автора по контексту). Тогда оборот  является аналогом придаточного предложения.


И по всем законам справедлИвости, ты самая настоящая пособница преступления.
Примеры:
По закону справедливости он стоит нескольких.
И по закону справедливости, сегодня я обязан сесть с тобой.
Дележ, совершаемый по всем законам справедливости между однокашницами бывшей скотницы, не успокоил, однако, шумного их сборища.
Карта слов
